# Can I send a PNREF from a previous transaction when using Hosted Pages?

Tags: payflowpro

We are currently testing (successfully) credit card payments from our accounting software using the hosted page. Given the PNREF that is returned in the Silent Post, can I use that as an ORIGID when requesting the hosted page for subsequent payments (until it expires, of course)? Is it simply a matter of including ORIGID along with SECURETOKENid and SECURETOKEN in the parameters when launching the payment page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the PNREF is for a Credit Card transaction (`TENDER=C`), then you can use it for reference transactions that require an ORIGID.

If the PNREF is for a PayPal transaction (`TENDER=P`), this will not work unless you have a PayPal Billing Agreement on file as part of that original transaction, and even then I think you're supposed to use the BAID, although it may work both ways.